# type parameter inference + higher order types + type classes = :-(

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz, typeclass

```scala
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

def foo[M[_]:MonadPlus,A](a:A) = a.point[M]
// foo: [M[_], A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: scalaz.MonadPlus[M])M[A]

def bar1[M[_]:MonadPlus](i:Int): M[Int] = 
  foo(i) // <-- error: ambiguous implicit values

// this works, but why?  Isn't it just the same?
def bar2[M[_]:MonadPlus](i:Int): M[Int] = 
  foo(i)(implicitly[MonadPlus[M]])

def bar3[M[_]](i:Int)(implicit m:MonadPlus[M]): M[Int] = 
  foo(i)(m) // slightly less surprising that this works

def bar4[M[_]:MonadPlus](i:Int): M[Int] = 
  foo[M,Int](i) // this also works, but why?
```

build.sbt:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.0-M5"
```

(although I get the same result in 2.10.0-RC3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same error message if you simply write:

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

def foo[M[_]:MonadPlus,A](a:A) = a.point[M]

foo(1) // <-- error: ambiguous implicit values
       // both value listInstance ...
       // and value optionInstance ...
```

My understanding is that the compiler tries to typecheck the "body" of the `bar1` method and without considering that there may be a `MonadPlus[M]` instance in scope (brought by the `bar` definition), it already finds 2 specific `MonadPlus[M]` instances (listInstance and optionInstance) which are suitable for a `foo` invocation. At this stage it just declares an ambiguity.

Then in `bar2` and `bar3` you specify explicitly the instance to use and in `bar4` you give the type parameters which are `M` and `Int` which is not ambiguous on the `foo` call because the only implicit in scope with these constraints is `implicitly[MonadPlus[M]]`.

Comment: Oops, yeah.  A year later the answer seems obvious to me.  `bar1` doesnt specify what kind of `MonadPlus` to pass to `foo`; `bar2`,`bar3`,`bar4` do, either through explicit arguments or type arguments.  Honestly I don't know what I was thinking.